# Difference between List.ContentTypesEnabled & List.AllowContentTypes

Tags: list, development, rest, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api

I would like to enable content types on lists with REST. Microsoft says this about these properties:

> List.AllowContentTypes: Gets a value that specifies whether the list supports content types. Returns Boolean true if list supports content
>   types otherwise returns false.
>
> List.ContentTypesEnabled: Gets or sets a value that specifies whether content types are enabled for the list. Returns Boolean true if content types are
>   enabled for the list otherwise returns false.

It looks like AllowContentTypes is used as a getter only, while ContentTypesEnabled is used to set or get the value.

However I was reading how to change content types in code, and the REST request used by Microsoft docs is like this:

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /lists(guid'51925dd7-2108-481a-b1ef-4bfa4e69d48b')
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 100,
    'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Test title' }",
  headers: { 
    "IF-MATCH”: "*",
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

So they're using the AllowContentTypes (the one which was supposed to be a getter), to update the list to allow content types.

Can anyone explain this please? What should I be using and why?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your question here is. However, I will put here all I know related to this.

As you already said, **AllowContentTypes** determines if you can **manage** content types (updating an existing content type or creating a new content type) in a particular list. 
For example, lists of type **Survey, Wiki page library** etc do not support content type management. So they will have **AllowContentTypes** set to false.

And in case, if you try to update **ContentTypesEnabled** to true when **AllowContentTypes** value is false for a particular list, it throws an exception like this "**This list does not allow content types**"

Coming to **ContentTypesEnabled**, setting this to true allows the user to create/update content types present in that list.

FYR [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314797/difference-between-splist-contenttypesenabled-and-splist-allowcontenttypes)